# BuildHive Jenkins build error

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to use Cloudbees' BuildHive service to build my GitHub-hosted project - [bkemu-android](https://github.com/3cky/bkemu-android). This is android-maven-plugin controlled project, so [Jenkins job](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/job/3cky/job/bkemu-android/) was created using "Maven job" template. But project build is just failing constantly with some obscure log message:

> Parsing POMs
>   [bkemu-android] $ /usr/bin/tenant-isolate /opt/jdk/jdk1.6.latest/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /scratch/jenkins/maven3-agent.jar:/opt/maven/latest/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/maven/latest /scratch/jenkins/slave.jar /scratch/jenkins/maven3-interceptor.jar 52322
>
> setup process failed (1): Success
>
> ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1

What I should change in my project or BuildHive job settings to successfully build my project?

Comment: I'm not familar with CloundBees, but can you add a Maven option: `-X` to the Jenkins job configuration?

Comment: @unhillbilly this is free account and it seems it doesn't allow to change job configuration. All I can change on settings page it's build goals list.